# View child node data in result with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, projection, nosql-aggregation

I m trying to view child node data in mongodb

The query i have written in mongodb is -

```
db.users.aggregate({$unwind: '$social'} ,  
{ $project : { name: '$name' ,fb: '$social.facebook'  }  } );
```

I want to view only the name and facebook fields only

But its showing the data as -

```
 /* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("583d94b42a7b4dfc334d1ab7"),
"name" : "Person Name",
"fb" : "www.fb.com/maria.mongodb"
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("583d94b42a7b4dfc334d1ab7"),
"name" : "Person Name"
}

/* 3 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("583da2a52a7b4dfc334d1ab8"),
"name" : "Some Name",
"fb" : "www.fb.com/some.name"
}

/* 4 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("583da2a52a7b4dfc334d1ab8"),
"name" : "Some Name"
}
```

as you see the data in the 2 and 4 data are **without the fb fields.**

The raw data that I am having is -

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("583d94b42a7b4dfc334d1ab7"),
"name" : "Person Name",
"social" : [ 
    {
        "facebook" : "www.fb.com/maria.mongodb",
        "privacy" : true
    }, 
    {
        "twitter" : "www.tw.com/mongodb",
        "privacy" : false
    }
],
"personal" : [ 
    {
        "cell_no" : "+1-99082198414",
        "privacy" : true
    }, 
    {
        "email" : "maria@mongodb.com",
        "privacy" : false
    }
]
 }

 /* 2 */
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("583da2a52a7b4dfc334d1ab8"),
"name" : "Some Name",
"social" : [ 
    {
        "facebook" : "www.fb.com/some.name",
        "privacy" : true
    }, 
    {
        "twitter" : "www.tw.com/mongodb",
        "privacy" : false
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you need to match on only documents where social.facebook exists before your projection.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$social' },
    { $match: { 'social.facebook': { $exists: true } } },
    { $project : { _id: 0, name: '$name', fb: '$social.facebook'  } }
]);
```

Results in the following:

```
{ "name" : "Person Name", "fb" : "www.fb.com/maria.mongodb" }
{ "name" : "Some Name", "fb" : "www.fb.com/some.name" }
```

Comment: _id:0 for hiding the ids

Comment: Yes, didn't know you wanted that also.